# C++ Makefile error: No rule to make target

Tags: c++, makefile

we are trying to put together a Makefile on an Ubuntu server.

the file structure is like this:

```
/project
Makefile
/files
    /src
    [all .cpp files, including main.cpp]
    /include
    [all .h files]
    /obj
```

**Terminal outputs:**

make: *** No rule to make target `files/obj/%.o', needed by`sas'.  Stop.

My Makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
OBJECTS=main.o Parser.o People.o Person.o Queries.o Relation.o
SOURCES=main.cpp Parser.cpp People.cpp Person.cpp Queries.cpp Relation.cpp

all: sas

sas: files/obj/%.o
        $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o sas

files/obj/%.o: files/src/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES)
```

Comment: Did you mean to have nothing in `project`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for us:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11
SOURCES=$(wildcard Hackathon/src/*.cpp)

sas: $(SOURCES:Hackathon/src/%.cpp=Hackathon/obj/%.o)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@

Hackathon/obj/%.o: Hackathon/src/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a *lot* of problems with this makefile. It would take too long to fix them one by one (I tried, and it took hundreds of lines), so let's start from scratch. How would we build this executable, if we were doing it by hand? Like this:

```
g++ -c -Wall files/src/main.cpp -o files/obj/main.o
g++ -c -Wall files/src/Parser.cpp -o files/obj/Parser.o
...
g++ -c -Wall files/src/Relation.cpp -o files/obj/Relation.o
g++ -Wall files/obj/main.o files/obj/Parser.o ... files/obj/Relation.o -o sas
```

To build the object files, we write a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), using [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
CXX=g++

files/obj/%.o: files/src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -Wall $< -o $@
```

To build the executable, we use a constructed list of objects:

```
MODULES = main Parser People Person Queries Relation
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %, files/obj/%.o, $(MODULES))

sas: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@
```

Notice that there's no need for `SOURCES` at all. **I think that maintaining a list of sources or objects in the makefile is a good idea** (because that way multiple projects can share source files without complicating the directory structure all to hell), but there's no reason to maintain two such lists.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to maintain the list of sources manually, do you? You want

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
SOURCES=$(wildcard files/src/*.cpp)

sas: $(SOURCES:files/src/%.cpp=files/obj/%.o)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

files/obj/%.o: files/src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```